# Can not get cancancan working with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, cancancan

I have devise properly set up & working. Rolify seems like its all OK. Cancancan seems like its installed correctly.

When I do this in a view

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <% if current_user.has_role? "admin" %>
    User is signed in
  <% else %>
   User is NOT signed in
 <% end %>
```

it works as expected

My ability.rb is as follows (as per the docs)

```
def initialize(user)
  user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
  if user.admin?
    can :manage, :all
  else
    can :read, :all
  end
end
```

user.rb is

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

devise :avatarable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
    :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
devise :avatarable, :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:facebook]
rolify

etc. 

etc.
```

and category.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId

  resourcify
end
```

in the rails console if I do the following on a user I know has the admin role

```
user.has_role? :admin
```

I get => true

Am I missing something totally obvious? Ive checked everywhere and cant figure it out.

Comment: I'll add that if I go to categories/xxxx/edit as a logged out user or a non admin user I can still see & edit everything

Comment: Are you authorizing your controller actions (load_and_authorize_resource) and checking abilities in your views (<% if can? :update, @article %>)?  See https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan.

Comment: Thank you sir. That worked like a charm. I was following s tutorial on cancancan, rolify & devise and that was the one piece missing from the tut.